# Need help to combine two powershell commands to automate port forwarding in docker (on vmware)

Tags: powershell, docker, vmware

I am using Docker with Vmware workstation and dockermachine.
(not the default hyper v)

Docker works quite well, but I need to manually tell the system
to do port forwarding from the container to the docker host.

I can do that with this line

```
ssh docker@$(docker-machine ip dev) -f -N -L 5006:localhost:5006
```

That works well.

Now I am running a lot of containers and they change often so typing this 
in every time is time consuming and should be automated.

With docker ps I can get a list of containers and their port mappings.
Using powershell to clean it up

```
docker ps --format "{{.Ports}}"|ForEach-Object{($PSItem -split ":|-")[1]}
```

I get a list of ports

```
5023
5210
5205
5303
5006
5105
5016
```

This is good.

What I dont know is how do I take this list I generated in Powershell
and write a magic Powershell incantation that executes the command

```
ssh docker@$(docker-machine ip dev) -f -N -L $PORT:localhost:$PORT
```

For every port number in the list I get from

```
docker ps --format "{{.Ports}}"|ForEach-Object{($PSItem -split ":|-")[1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a `foreach` loop:

```
$list = & docker ps --format '{{.Ports}}' | ForEach-Object { ($PSItem -split ':|-')[1] }
foreach ($port in $list)
{
    & ssh docker@$(& docker-machine ip dev) -f -N -L ${port}:localhost:$port
}
```

Note without the `${}` syntax, the colon will be seen as a drive/scope modifier.

---

### [about_Foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-5.1)

### [about_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1)

### [about_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 0):

If the output of ports is just a single string:

```
$portList = docker ps --format "{{.Ports}}"|ForEach-Object{($PSItem -split ":|-")[1]}
[Array]$portListParsed = $portList.Split(' ')
foreach($port in $portListParsed)
{
     Invoke-Command -Command $(ssh docker@$(docker-machine ip dev) -f -N -L $port:localhost:$port)
}
```

I'm not sure of the docker syntax with $PORT:localhost:$PORT from your post, but if you have a constant for the first one, you could just set that as a separate variable and switch it out.

Comment: External programs, by default, output to the success stream as an *array* of strings FYI.  Your `Invoke-Command` call is also completely unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks @TheIncorrigible1 for the tip